# Unable to run a service via the react native bridge

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a native module in Java which is responsible for running a service in background.

I have this method in `ClassA`:

```
  @ReactMethod
    public void startService(final Promise promise) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getCurrentActivity(), BackgroundService.class);
        intent.putExtra(BackgroundService.FILENAME, "test123.html");
        intent.putExtra(BackgroundService.URL,
        "http://www.vogella.com/index.html");

         Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

         if (currentActivity == null) {
            promise.reject("Activity doesnt exist");
         } else {
            getCurrentActivity().startService(intent);
         }
    }
```

Here is the code in `BackgroundService`:

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
public static final String URL = "urlpath";
public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
public static final String RESULT = "result";
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.vogella.android.service.receiver";

  public BackgroundService() {
      super("BackgroundService");
  }
  public String getName() {
      return "BackgroundService";
  }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //do stuff
    ClassA.servicePromise.resolve("done with service!");

 }
```

`servicePromise` is defined in classA as so :
`public static Promise servicePromise = null`;

The problem, if I am understanding it correctly, is that `getCurrentActivity.startService(intent)` does not execute *properly*. I am able to successfully return a promise inside `startService` after `getCurrentActivity.startService(intent)`, so I know the problem is not with how I am calling `startService`. However, I am unable to return the promise from inside `BackgroundService`, which is what I want.

Inside the `onHandleIntent`, I tried calling `ClassA.servicePromise.resolve("done with service!");` before executing any other code just to test if it works, but it doesn't.

In my manifest, I have added the `service` as follows:

```
  <service android:name="com.smaplePakcage.name.BackgroundService"
        android:exported="false">
     </service>
```